# trying to updates the pod files getting the error in the terminal

Tags: ios, objective-c, terminal, cocoapods

```
[!] The target `project name` is declared twice.
```

when i m trying to update the pod files in the terminal,i am getting the error in the above..kindly help..

**i have tried to uninstall and reinstalling the pod files but still giving the same error.kindly give a step by step process as i am new in this concepts.**
how can i update my pod files . there is another error that is shown in the app when i run the app.

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-aditestdemo
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

for this i am updating the pod files kindly help me out. what i can do to rum my app.

Comment: can you paste your path which you are trying in terminal so we can get idea what is the exact issue.

Comment: <!--Silicons-Mac-mini:~ silicon2$ cd /Users/silicon2/Desktop/ADI\ \&\ MICROJOBS\ 6\:2\:17/ADI_Dec05\ 4 -->
this is the path sir @DarshanKunjadiya

Comment: put code of podfile here would help, also the error when you run the app because you update but it fail, so it consider missing

Comment: **# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, ‘9.2’
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'aditestdemo' do
    
platform :ios, ‘9.2’
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
end

target 'aditestdemo' do

end

**

Comment: `The target "project name" is declared twice.` warning is because you have defined *aditestdemo* twice in the podfile. You can remove the empty target. Secondly, (just to verify) - after running pod install, you opened the .xcworkspace and not .xcodeproj right?

Answer (score 0):

this is because when you hit update command from terminal, this updates your existing pod file . There is 
To remove bug just do :- 
(1).delete podfile, podfile.lock, Pods, and your .xcworkspace.
(2).and reinit pod file and install it your project path.

Refer the link this will clear your doubt:- 
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html